# Passing a function with an "implicit" argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I'm using a class from a package in Python to which I pass functions that must have **only one argument**, e.g. :

```
def exampleFunction1(only_argument_1):
    
    doSomething1(only_argument_1) #perform some operations
```

Then, once defined all the needed functions in the above way, I need to pass them in this way:

```
python_package_class.function1 = exampleFunction1
python_package_class.function2 = exampleFunction2
python_package_class.function3 = exampleFunction3
```

Now let's imagine that the doSomething is equal for all my functions, except for the fact that it requires another parameter that change, e.g. (1, 2 and 3 are just examples, the argument can be anything):

```
def exampleFunction1(only_argument_1):
    
    doSomething(1, only_argument_1) #perform some operations

def exampleFunction2(only_argument_2):
    
    doSomething(2, only_argument_2) #perform some operations

def exampleFunction3(only_argument_3):
    
    doSomething(3, only_argument_3) #perform some operations
```

This could be greatly simplified by defining **only one exampleFunction** to which I pass **two parameters**:

```
def exampleFunction(a, only_argument_1):
    
    doSomething(a, only_argument_1) #perform some operations
```

But, unfortunately, this would give me an error since, as I said, the Python package that I'm using strictly requires functions accepting only one argument.

So my question is, **is there an "implicit way" to pass the argument** `a` **to exampleFunction in the following code line?**

```
python_package_class.function1 = exampleFunction
```

Comment: Cant you pass your two parameters inside a tuple or list. that way the function takes just one argument which is a tuple or list. but that argument then contains inside it any number of elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def exampleFunction(a, only_argument_1):
    doSomething(a, only_argument_1)

python_package_class.function1 = partial(exampleFunction, 1)
python_package_class.function2 = partial(exampleFunction, 2)
python_package_class.function3 = partial(exampleFunction, 3)
```

The `partial` function is used for partial function application which “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature.

Here is an example:

```
from functools import partial

def f(arg1, arg2):
    print(f'{arg1} {arg2}')

f1 = partial(f, 1)
f2 = partial(f, 2)
f3 = partial(f, 3)

print(f1('a')) # '1 a'
print(f2('a')) # '2 a'
print(f3('b')) # '3 b'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass your parameters in a tuple which is one argument but would contain inside it any number of elements. you can then pass this to your second function expanding it into its individual parameters. Example:

```py
def example_function(arg_list):
    other_function(*arg_list)


def other_function(arg_one, arg_two):
    print(f"received args: '{arg_one}', '{arg_two}'")


args = (1, "some_arg")
example_function(args)
args2 = (2, "some_arg")
example_function(args2)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
received args: '1', 'some_arg'
received args: '2', 'some_arg'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've never thought about this solution, and this could work but it is not straightforward to implement. I will try.